# Spring data Neo4j: persist() method undefined

Tags: spring, persistence, neo4j, graph-databases, spring-data-neo4j

Pretty new to graph databases, neo4j and spring. I have a simple POJO annotated with @NodeEntity. But, against the wisdom of many online tutorials I read on the matter, my POJO doesn't have any persist() method to save it to the graph DB.

What sort of black magic do I need to do to make this method available to my POJOs, or are the tutorials out of date and the way to save to DB has changed with the version of Spring I'm using (2.1.0-RELEASE)?

Comment: usually you use `neo4jTemplate.save(entity)`to save your entities, Active-Record-style persistence is only possible with AspectJ and so "advanced"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The black magic you're referring to is [AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/). The advanced mapping mode of Spring Data Neo4j uses aspectJ to enhance your pojos. "persist()" is one of the methods that the aspectj compiler adds to your pojos when building the project.

Check [chapter 21 "Environment Setup"](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#setup) in the Spring Data Neo4j Guide Book to see how to setup your project to use the advanced mapping mode with aspectj.

Comment: Makes me wonder: why is such an important method mentioned only in the advanced section of the guide book in the last chapters?